# .then() is not returning a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, es6-promise

I am trying to import a function from another file and while rendering in the react component, it doesn't get rendered. The value of that variable is showing `undefined`

index.js

```js
const GetOwnBalance = async () => {
    if (!isInitialized) {
        await init();
    }
    // const web2 = new Web3(provider);
    nftContract.methods
    .getBalance(selectedAccount)
        .call()
        .then((balance) => {
            // console.log(`Balance of ${selectedAccount} is ${balance}`);
            console.log("Intermediate balance : " + balance);
            // return balance;
        }   
    );
};
export default GetOwnBalance;
```

Until this everything runs perfect, but the problem is in App.js

App.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import  GetOwnBalance  from './index';

function App() {
    const [balance, setBalance] = useState(0);
    function fetchBalance() {
        GetOwnBalance()
            .then(value => {
                setBalance(value); //value shows undefined ???
                console.log("Final Balance : " + value);
            }
                
            );
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <p>Your balance is {balance}</p>
            <button onClick={fetchBalance}>Refresh balance</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

When I try to run this piece of code, the `value` value in the .then() promise shows undefined. Can someone please explain why is it so?

Comment: How do you expect value to get reassigned between setValue and console.log?

Comment: Are you saying that you're seeing: _"Final Balance : undefined"_ in your console?

Comment: @NickParsons Yes

Comment: Why are you mixing await with then? It would make a lot more sense to use await in both cases, i.e. `const balance = await nftContract.methods.getBalance(selectedAccount).call()`

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not returning anything from function `GetOwnBalance`.

Try adding the `return` keyword in `return nftContract.methods....`

```
const GetOwnBalance = async () => {
    if (!isInitialized) {
        await init();
    }
    // const web2 = new Web3(provider);
   return nftContract.methods
    .getBalance(selectedAccount)
        .call()
        .then((balance) => {
            // console.log(`Balance of ${selectedAccount} is ${balance}`);
            console.log("Intermediate balance : " + balance);
            // return balance; <-- Also uncomment this
        }   
    );
};
export default GetOwnBalance;
```

Comment: Since the last `.then()` callback function doesn't returning anything, the promise will resolve to `undefined`. You can fix that though by uncommenting the `return balance;`. But as CherryDT mentioned in an above comment, it is better to stick with either just `await` or `.then()` rather than mix the two.

Comment: @NickParson is correct that you need also to uncomment  //return balance;

Answer (score -2):

Is the "GetOwnBalance" function located at index.js or ./Web3Client'?

Instead of "value" parameter on

```
 .then(value => {
            setBalance(balance); //value shows undefined ???
            console.log("Final Balance : " + balance);
        }
```

Try just using the hook value name:

```
 .then(() => {
            setBalance(value);
            console.log("Final Balance : " + value);
        })
```

Additionally you don't have to set "GetOwnBalance" as async if you don't use await

Comment: Unfortunately, this code isn't going to change much. Changing it to use `setBalance(balance);` will just set the state back to what is currently is, so the state doesn't update at all in this case so there is no use in calling `setBalance()`. In the second code block, the `value` parameter has been omitted from `() => {`, so this will throw an error when the `value` variable is used. The core problem is with their `GetOwnBalance` function (which was different when the question was originally posted, but the OP has updated it now)